# most efficient way to work with big data from cx_oracle in python

Tags: python, oracle

I want to ask in general, for right path that i should go to work with data downloaded from oracle database, to python via cx_Oracle.

Right now i have created `oracle_dataframe` with content from database, its hughe.
I will use in code for example: `for file in files:` and compare data from each file with this `oracle_dataframe` and search what i need.

As we know it's not efficient to hold oracle content in variable, and downloading it all the time, over and over.

So my thoughts are, maybe i should create something like python database where i can place oracle content and only making updates from oracle ?

Someone here did something like that before? i heard that i can use mongo db , but i want to ask for your approach .

Cheers

Comment: If your data is already in one DB, it doesn't make sense to move it to another DB to process it.  It sounds like you should be doing the processing in PL/SQL inside the DB.

Comment: right, it is already in another DB, but if i need lets say to compare those records for each file, i need to download this data from external DB each time, it takes time, so that why i thought about personal DB with all data in python. In this way i will only search for records, like from dataframe. am i right?